# Understanding Gradle dynamic tasks

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm reading about [dynamic tasks in gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html) and want to understand the syntax and meaning of the following code:

```
4.times { counter ->
    task "task$counter" << {
        println "I'm task number $counter"
    }
}
task0.dependsOn task2, task3
```

1. What does `4.times` mean? Why `4`?
2. What does `->` mean? Now I understand it as a way to pass a parameter to a task. I'm sure its correct strictly speaking about groovy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle based on Groovy and you can programming in gradle like in groovy or java. For your questions:

1. Look this http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2009/09/groovy-goodness-looping-in-different.html
2. Look this http://www.groovy-lang.org/closures.html

Answer (score 4):

1. 4 is just a random value, you can pick 10 or 15 as well. This value is just used to create multiple tasks. Under the hood [this](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#times(java.lang.Number,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) method is invoked for `times` - think of it as if it was an iterator.
2. `->` is used to indicate a closure param name. Without it, it would look like this:

   ```
   4.times { 
      task "task$it" << {
         println "I'm task number $counter"
      }
   }
   task0.dependsOn task2, task3
   ```

   Since `it` is default closure param name. If multiples closures are used (as in the example - for `times` and for adding an action), it's good practice to use dedicated names for closures. Here are the [docs](http://www.groovy-lang.org/closures.html) about closures.

Comment: As abhi mentioned, `$counter` should be replaced with `$it` in your snippet.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is an extension to Opal's answer.

I made a build script with the above code and executed the following Gradle commands.

### `$ gradle tasks`

> **Output**
>
> ```
> Other tasks
> -----------
> task0
> task1
> task2
> task3
> ...
> ```

Which means the code basically creates 4 tasks (shown in the output), this happens because of the `4.times{...}` part. It executes the inner `closure` 4 times passing in the value for the parameter `counter` each time.

### `$ gradle task3 -q`

> **Output**
>
> ```
> I'm task number 3
> ```

This happens because the `println` statement prints the respective counter variable's value for each task, which in this case is *3*.

I addition, I would like to point out that the code snippet given by Opal won't work. Since he removed any explicit parameters, the variable `counter` won't be recognised any more.